# How to redirect to a certain window.location.hash from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to redirect from homepage www.example.com to www.example.com/portfolio/#works

I have tried inserting the id to the

containing the information but the original theme has a data-filter=""; attribute so it is not fetching the required content

Comment: Please edit your post with your code and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
And especially look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: ok thank you I have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one that can be considered canonical to navigate to a new URL is

```
window.location = 'www.example.com/portfolio/#works'
```

If you want to redirect to a different path, on the same domain, use:

```
window.location.pathname = '/portfolio/#works'
```

This is using the location object offered by the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), [Location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Methods)

Comment: I believe `window.location` is unrelated to the history API.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your index to redirect to the given address.

```
header("Location: www.example.com/portfolio/#works");
die();
```

I hope i understood you correctly.

Comment: What happened? Can you give more info

Comment: @NobMusic Why cant you change the href on the a tag?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers it was really helpful
I have successfully completed the task with this code snippet

```
console.log(document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1)).click());
```

Now when a user visits the site, click on the expected tab 
www.example.com/portfolio/#works
it redirects to the portfolio page then fetch the hash url (#works) as the new id and click on the tab again automatically